# Buildbot Triggerable Scheduler and working dir relation

Tags: buildbot

Trying to setup a Triggerable Scheduler in buildbot nine (0.9.1) but I think I'm misunderstanding how this is supposed to work.
I have two builders:

- CompilerBuilder
- PackageBuilder

Last step of the CompilerBuilder is a trigger step:

```
steps.Trigger (schedulerNames=['package'],
               waitForFinish=True)
```

The master configuration file has a Triggerable scheduler:

```
c['schedulers'].append(schedulers.Triggerable(
    name="package", 
    builderNames=['package']))
```

**What I want to achieve/expect**

- A SingleBranch Scheduler starts the CompilerBuilder
- When the CompilerBuilder reaches the last step, the PackageBuilder is triggered, so the freshly compiled software is packaged.

**What really happens**

- The SingleBranch Scheduler starts the CompilerBuilder
- When the CompilerBuilder reaches the last step, the PackageBuilder is triggered

...so far so good, unfortunately the PackageBuilder is started inside a different working dir from the one where the code has been checked-out and compiled, so the package creation process fails.

My understanding was that a Triggered builder would be run in the same working dir of the "calling" builder but I think I'm not understanding how to correctly configure the builders/schedulers correcty.

Any hint?

Comment: Why not pass working dir through property?

Comment: @ayaye might be an option but I'd really like to understand how this is supposed to work. I would expect that the working dir was "implicitly" passed between the builders from trigger-er to triggered. I cannot figure out the use case otherwise

Comment: in general, these builders have different working dirs. For example, the first one builds library and the second one builds other component that depends on that library. Obviosly, they have different working dirs.

Comment: @ayaye  if you summarize your comments as an answer I'll mark as a valid solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, each builder has it own working directory.  I recommend using addSteps (not addStep) with a list of package steps as part of the single branch scheduler builder.  If you don't always want to package, add a doStepIf with some additional logic.